# OS X Mail Mavericks 10.9 Gmail accounts NOT in sync

Tags: mail.app, gmail

In OS X Mavericks 10.9.2 after doing all the updates my Gmail accounts still show messages that are in the inbox but when I login to gmail on the browser, they aren't there.

Is there a way to fix this? I don't remember this happening before. I am using IMAP.

I use IMAP on OS X and use the exchange setup on my phone/iPad. All my accounts are gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Try "Get Account Info" by right-clicking on the mailbox, which will force Mail to search through the IMAP account for messages and seems to rebuild all mailboxes in the account.

See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/116487/43770) for further suggestions if that fails.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article for you](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/laptops/news/apple-posts-workaround-for-mail-sync-issues-permanent-fix-not-yet-available-479097).

There is a work around proposed b Apple but no permanent fix.

> Apple posts workaround for Mavericks Mail sync issues, no permanent
>   fix yet
>
> by NDTV Correspondent, February 04, 2014
>
> inShare2
>
> [image: mail sync]
>
> There's good news and bad news for users of Apple's Mail app who have
>   been plagued by problems since updating to OS X Mavericks. Apple has
>   acknowledged that users are still having trouble despite multiple
>   updates since a new version of Mail first released with the updated
>   operating system, but the suggested fix is only a temporary
>   workaround.
>
> Apple suggests that users disconnect and reconnect from their mail
>   servers by selecting 'Take All Accounts Offline' and then clicking
>   'Get All New Mail' from the Mailbox menu. This has the same effect as
>   quitting and restarting the app, which is what many users had resorted
>   to doing. Apple also helpfully adds that these two commands can be
>   added to Mail's main toolbar by clicking 'View > Customize Toolbar'
>   and then dragging them from the palette that pops up to the desired
>   position.
>
> The workaround does not fix the underlying problem, although Apple's
>   acknowledgment means they know it exists and are hopefully working on
>   it already.
>
> Since the release of Mavericks, also known as OS X v10.9, users have
>   complained that the Mail app refuses to download new emails and that
>   they have trouble while moving and deleting messages, especially when
>   connected to Gmail accounts. Such problems relate to the desktop
>   software's inability to synchronise changes with remote mail servers.
>
> Two previous updates, including a dedicated Mail Update and the
>   overall Mavericks 10.9.1 release failed to fix these problems for many
>   users. Apple's release notes for 10.9.1 specifically mention improved
>   support for Gmail, reliability fixes, and improved search and mailbox
>   functionality.
>
> Other problems relate to mail being delivered late, folders and tags
>   not updating, and searches not displaying messages that are known to
>   exist.

What I read from it, is Apple knows about the IMAP issues and it is working to fix it. So far the 10.9.2 has not completely resolved it.

I suggest you open the Activity window in Mail to monitor the progress if you have multiple accounts (it might take a while), before doing the get mail (go online)

Answer (score -1):

The only thing that worked for me: enabling 2-step authentication with gmail.

Comment: You might want to provide steps here